# What is a great, all-purpose knife?

Tags: gear, camping, survival

I'm going to go camping soon and would like to have a dependable knife that I can use when I'm there.

What do you guys recommend? Not to be *that guy* or anything, but I'd prefer if it was American made, and could buy it in store (online is fine, too). Thanks!

Comment: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/what-to-look-for-when-purchasing-a-fixed-blade-knife